# How to split a big pattern match into multiple modules?

Tags: module, pattern-matching, ocaml

Use-case: I have a small game engine which is based on XML. Each XML element should be parsed. There are elements like `<deck>` and `<dice>`. Right now, I have a huge pattern match clause which reads like this

```
match xml_element with
| Xml.Element ("deck", [("some_attribute", value)], card_children) ->
    ...
| Xml.Element ("dice", ...
```

It goes on. I want to split it into modules, so that I have a Deck module, a Dice module, and so on. How do I properly pattern match on the XML elements and call the different modules? With a list of modules that I iterate and return `None` if there's no match inside each particular module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by Drup (Gabriel Radanne) on IRC:

```
let l = [Mod1.f; Mod2.f; Mod3.f]
```

and you try each one, in order.

all the functions must have the same signature

it's "poor man's modular patter match" :)

but it's a classical technique

it's most often use for modular error handling, in the compiler in particular

Edit: A way to automatically populate the list is by "register functions", `let _ ...`, in each module.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use nested pattern matchings:

```
match xml_element with
| Xml.Element ("deck", attributes, card_children) -> match attributes with
   | [("some_attribute", value)] -> …
   | …
| Xml.Element ("dice", attributes, dice_children) -> …
| …
```

You then can refactor the inner ones into helper functions, and finally move them to their own modules.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure it's good enough. Particularly, I'd like to be able to add new modules without touching old code.

Comment: @OlleHärstedt you'll always have to touch the code of the top-level parser to extend its functionality. But yeah, if the patterns and the helper-function calls become too repetitive, you may as well go with your idea of putting them in an appropriate data structure and looking them up in there (I'd probably avoid looping and rather use a map).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [extensible variant type](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.10/htmlman/extensiblevariants.html) can help you. They allow you to extend a variant type using the `+=` construction.
Let's say you have the following type:

```
type thing = .. (* type thing is open, we can later add constructors to it *)

let handle_thing = function
| _ -> failwith "unknown constructor"

type thing += Dice (* we add the constructor Dice to our type thing *)

let handle_thing = function
  | Dice -> print_string "i handle dice"
  | x -> handle_thing x

type thing += Deck (* we add the constructor Deck to our type thing *)

let handle_thing = function
  | Deck -> print_string "i handle deck"
  | x -> handle_thing x
```

This allows you to progressivelly extend your type **while** implementing its processing. You can than of course split the whole thing into several modules.

However, note that (from the doc)

> pattern matching on an extensible variant type requires a default case
>   to handle unknown variant constructors.

Comment: Hm, but I'd still have to convert from Xml.Element to `thing`? The XML type comes from a third-party library (light-xml).

Comment: Yes of course, wich i supposed you wanted to do. If you prefer working with the type ````string````, the same thing applies except you dont have to extend it anymore